# Как сконвертировать makefile в CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake, makefile

Есть проект на `makefile`. Мне нужно его собрать. Когда я импортирую проект в `CLion`, автоматически создается `CMakeLists.txt` по исходникам. При этом игнорируется `makefile`.

Как сгенерировать `CMakeLists.txt` по `makefile` (не ручками)?

Comment: имеющийся makefile был сгенерирован прграммой cmake? если нет, то какой смысл обращать на него внимание?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я не знаю, каким образом был получен исходный makefile, у меня задача по нему получить файл cmake-а и им собрать проект

Comment: дело в том, что программа [cmake](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) предназначена именно для генерации makefile-ов. и если makefile у вас есть, то ничего генерировать уже не надо, а всего лишь запустить программу make.

Answer (score -1):

> Как сгенерировать `CMakeLists.txt` по `makefile` (не ручками)?

*Автоматически* преобразовать makefile в CMakeLists.txt **невозможно**.

Задача примерно похожа на преобразование ассемблерного кода в код на языке высокого уровня (в т.ч Си).

В Make и CMake есть общие концепции, но реализованы они по-разному, на разных уровнях детализации. Поэтому преобразование скриптов из одного формата в другой обычно производится вручную, но по известным принципам.